# What does "fluffy duffy" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

This is a nickname for a cute dog. So I think "fluffy" means "furry" but what's the whose phrase?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really mean anything as a phrase. *Fluffy* is close to what you said (it can be looked up in any dictionary). "Duffy" isn't a word at all. ("Duff" is, but that's not relevant.) It's just a silly-sounding name that rhymes.

More generally, it's an example of [baby talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_talk) where words are sometimes chosen, or even invented, for their sound more than for their meaning.